# api connection failed connect to Automation account using logicapp through bicep

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-bicep, azure-api-apps

```js
resource workflows_newlogic06_name_resource 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2016-06-01' = {
  name: workflows_newlogic06_name
  location:location
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      parameters: {
        '$connections': {
          defaultValue: {}
          type: 'Object'
        }
      }
      triggers: {
        Recurrence: {
          recurrence: {
            frequency: 'Month'
            interval: 3
          }
          evaluatedRecurrence: {
            frequency: 'Month'
            interval: 3
          }
          type: 'Recurrence'
        }
      }
      actions: {
        Create_job: {
          runAfter: {}
          type: 'ApiConnection'
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'azureautomation_1\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'put'
            path: '/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent(\'${subscriptionid}\')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent(\'nextone1\')}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent(\'newauto01\')}/jobs'
            queries: {
              wait: true
              'x-ms-api-version': '2015-10-31'
            }
          }
        }
        Get_job_output: {
          runAfter: {
            Create_job: [
              'Succeeded'
            ]
          }
          type: 'ApiConnection'
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'azureautomation_1\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'get'
            path: '/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent(\'{subscriptionid}\')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent(\'nextone1\')}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent(\'newauto01\')}/jobs/@{encodeURIComponent(body(\'Create_job\')?[\'properties\']?[\'jobId\'])}/output'
            queries: {
              'x-ms-api-version': '2015-10-31'
            }
          }
        }
      }
      outputs: {}
    }
    parameters: {
      '$connections': {
        value: {
          azureautomation_1: {
            connectionId: connections_azureautomation_externalid
            connectionName: 'azureautomation'
            id: '/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureautomation'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
resource connections_azureautomation_name_resource 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: connections_azureautomation_name
  location: location
  properties: {
    displayName: 'new-c0n-01'
    statuses: [
      {
        status: 'Ready'
      }
    ]
    customParameterValues: {}
    createdTime: '2023-09-26T11:35:24.8852931Z'
    changedTime: '2023-09-26T11:35:24.8852931Z'
    api: {
      name: connections_azureautomation_name
      displayName: 'Azure Automation'
      description: 'Azure Automation provides tools to manage your cloud and on-premises infrastructure seamlessly.'
      iconUri: 'https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/u/shgogna/globalperconnector-train1/1.0.1639.3312/${connections_azureautomation_name}/icon.png'
      brandColor: '#56A0D7'
      id:subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.web/locations/managedApis', location, 'azureautomation')
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
      }
  }
}
```

What I Need?
created azure automation account, runbook, logic app along with api connections using bicep. The deployment was successful but logicapp connections was not established trying from long got frustrated did some one help me finding out these. Thanks

tried with many ways of finding the solution set the parametervalueType='alternative' couldn't work out.

Comment: Any error when you trying to run the logic app after dpeloyment? The connection is probably missing some credentials ? How does the logic app authenticate to the automation account ?

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for your Reply.

Comment: I tried your code in my environment and was able to establish an API connection as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/I9JhT0b.png). @saistack1

Answer (score 0):

> Api connection failed connect to Automation account using logic App through bicep: -

After analyzing your code, it looks good to me, but I made a few changes and attached the modified code below.

These kind of issues with connection can occur with older Api versions. As a result, always use the most recent `Api version`. [`'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.logic/2019-05-01/workflows?pivots=deployment-language-bicep).

```bash
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param subscriptionid string = 'xxxxx'
param connections_azureautomation_name string = 'jahconn'
resource workflows_newlogic06_name_resource 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: 'newwf'
  location:location
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      parameters: {
        '$connections': {
          defaultValue: {}
          type: 'Object'
        }
      }
      triggers: {
        Recurrence: {
          recurrence: {
            frequency: 'Month'
            interval: 3
          }
          evaluatedRecurrence: {
            frequency: 'Month'
            interval: 3
          }
          type: 'Recurrence'
        }
      }
      actions: {
        Create_job: {
          runAfter: {}
          type: 'ApiConnection'
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'azureautomation_1\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'put'
            path: '/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent(\'${subscriptionid}\')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent(\'nextone1\')}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent(\'newauto01\')}/jobs'
            queries: {
              wait: true
              'x-ms-api-version': '2015-10-31'
            }
          }
        }
        Get_job_output: {
          runAfter: {
            Create_job: [
              'Succeeded'
            ]
          }
          type: 'ApiConnection'
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'azureautomation_1\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'get'
            path: '/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent(\'{subscriptionid}\')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent(\'nextone1\')}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent(\'newauto01\')}/jobs/@{encodeURIComponent(body(\'Create_job\')?[\'properties\']?[\'jobId\'])}/output'
            queries: {
              'x-ms-api-version': '2015-10-31'
            }
          }
        }
      }
      outputs: {}
    }
    parameters: {
      '$connections': {
        value: {
          azureautomation_1: {
            connectionName: 'azureautomation'
            connectionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', connections_azureautomation_name)
            id: '/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureautomation'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
resource connections_azureautomation_name_resource 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: connections_azureautomation_name
  location: location
  properties: {
    displayName: 'new-c0n-01'
    statuses: [
      {
        status: 'Ready'
      }
    ]
    customParameterValues: {}
    createdTime: '2023-09-26T11:35:24.8852931Z'
    changedTime: '2023-09-26T11:35:24.8852931Z'
    api: {
      name: connections_azureautomation_name
      displayName: 'Azure Automation'
      description: ''
      iconUri: 'https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/u/shgogna/globalperconnector-train1/1.0.1639.3312/${connections_azureautomation_name}/icon.png'
      brandColor: '#56A0D7'
      id:subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.web/locations/managedApis', location, 'azureautomation')
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
      }
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Jahnavi, Thanks for your reply I have deployed my code successfully But the problem here is Authentication issue if you go on to second screenshot it clearly says the status was error and when looking into  logic app work flow the step automation of create job was error. even though i tried with service principal and user assigned managed identity.

Comment: Ok will look into it and update. @saistack1